# Teradata merge column/parameter table.A.A does not exist

Tags: merge, teradata

I am trying to merge a temp table into my main table to avoid duplicates:

```
MERGE INTO MYTABLE A USING
    (
        SELECT Y, Z, X 
        FROM MYTABLE_TEMP T
        JOIN (SELECT X FROM TABLE_X 
        WHERE COLUMN_N = '81205' GROUP BY 1) S  ON S.X = T.X
    ) B
    ON (A.Y = B.Y) AND (A.X = B.X)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.LOAD_DS = B.LOAD_DS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (B.Y, B.Z, B.X, B.LOAD_DS );
```

I get the error: MERGE Failed. 3810: Column/Parameter 'MYTABLE.A.A' does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not qualify the target column name in the `SET` clause, the same rule exists for `UPDATE` statements.

```
MERGE INTO MYTABLE A USING
    (
        SELECT Y, Z, X 
        FROM MYTABLE_TEMP T
        JOIN (SELECT X FROM TABLE_X 
        WHERE COLUMN_N = '81205' GROUP BY 1) S  ON S.X = T.X
    ) B
    ON (A.Y = B.Y) AND (A.X = B.X)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET /*remove the A.*/ LOAD_DS = B.LOAD_DS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (B.Y, B.Z, B.X, B.LOAD_DS );
```